# Suggestions for visualising the correlation matrix of more than 300 variables in python?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, correlation

I have 300+ data columns. I am not able to visualise the correlation matrix. Is there any way to address such challenges?

Note: All the columns have continuous data.

Find below code that I am using currently.

```
corr = fan2.corr() 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

sns.heatmap(corr[(corr >= 0.5) | (corr <= -0.4)], 
            cmap='viridis', vmax=1.0, vmin=-1.0, linewidths=0.1,
            annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 8}, square=True);
```

Comment: If you data contains mixture of continuous and categorical features, try visualizing them separately.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing it this way:

```
corr = fan2.corr() 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))         
sns.heatmap(corr[(corr >= 0.5) | (corr <= -0.4)], 
        cmap='viridis', vmax=1.0, vmin=-1.0, linewidths=0.1,
        annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 8}, square=True,ax=ax);
```